# How I insert additional strings in this jquery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add fade-in and fade-out transitions in this script, so i want to insert `fadeOut(1000)` `fadeIn(1000)` in the script.

Here is the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var $box=jQuery(".post"),
        $bar=jQuery("a.bar_view");
    $dat=jQuery("a.dat_view");
    $dat.click(function () {
        $box.removeClass("bar");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        $bar.removeClass("active");
        jQuery.cookie("dat_style", 0);
        return false
    });
    $bar.click(function () {
        $box.addClass("bar");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        $dat.removeClass("active");
        jQuery.cookie("dat_style", 1);
        return false
    });
    if(jQuery.cookie("dat_style")==0) {
        $box.removeClass( "bar");
        $dat.addClass("active")
    } else {
        $box.addClass("bar");
        $bar.addClass("active")
    }
});
```

this is jQuery script for switch between grid and list views to display content.
This is the site, here i implemented this script: http://bbelog-megagrid.blogspot.com View the HTML Sources there.

This is a same example script transitions added:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
var elem=$('ul');      
$('#viewcontrols a').on('click',function(e) {
 if ($(this).hasClass('gridview')) {
  elem.fadeOut(1000, function () {
  elem.removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
  elem.fadeIn(1000);
         });      
 }
 else if($(this).hasClass('listview')) {
  elem.fadeOut(1000, function () {
  elem.removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
  elem.fadeIn(1000);
        });         
 }
});
});
```

I want to modify the first script like this one.

Comment: Wow, and where exactly do you want to insert those strings, or is anywhere just fine ?

Comment: plz elaborate the question.

Comment: Callbacks: `$box.fadeOut(function(){$(this).removeClass("bar").fadeIn();});`

Comment: Ruchir Gupta, I looking for answers.

Comment: Hi blex where i add your strings

Answer (score 0):

you can add those like this

```
$dat.click(function () {
        $box.removeClass("bar");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        $bar.removeClass("active"); 

        $bar.fadeOut(1000);
        $dat.fadeIn(1000);

        jQuery.cookie("dat_style", 0);
        return false
    });
    $bar.click(function () {
        $box.addClass("bar");
        jQuery(this).addClass("active");
        $dat.removeClass("active");

        $dat.fadeOut(1000);
        $bar.fadeIn(1000);
        jQuery.cookie("dat_style", 1);
        return false
    });
```

Comment: It's not Working. it's only take effect on List View button